# Fresh texlive 2018 installation problem

Tags: texlive-2018

I've just made a fresh installation of the texlive 2018, and have lualatex issue, but not pdflatex. Here a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
essai
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` it works fine and the log file is :

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.9.30)  30 SEP 2018 17:15
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**bob.tex
(./bob.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
No file bob.aux.
\openout1 = `bob.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./bob.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 199 strings out of 493875
 2116 string characters out of 6162474
 55862 words of memory out of 5000000
 3973 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 497 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,17p,111b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bob.pdf (1 page, 11015 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

with `lualatex` not output and the log file is :

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)  (format=lualatex 2018.9.30)  30 SEP 2018 17:17
 restricted system commands enabled.
**bob.tex
(./bob.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2018/09/24 2.90001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2018-09-21 2.6 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2018-09-21 2.6 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.
```

And here is the `profile.texlive` file :

```
    # texlive.profile written on Sun Sep 30 14:17:13 2018 UTC
# It will NOT be updated and reflects only the
# installation profile at installation time.
selected_scheme scheme-custom
TEXDIR /usr/local/texlive/2018
TEXMFCONFIG $TEXMFSYSCONFIG
TEXMFHOME $TEXMFLOCAL
TEXMFLOCAL /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR $TEXMFSYSVAR
binary_x86_64-linux 1
collection-basic 1
collection-binextra 1
collection-context 1
collection-fontsextra 1
collection-fontsrecommended 1
collection-fontutils 1
collection-formatsextra 1
collection-games 1
collection-langcjk 1
collection-langcyrillic 1
collection-langenglish 1
collection-langfrench 1
collection-langgerman 1
collection-langgreek 1
collection-latex 1
collection-latexextra 1
collection-latexrecommended 1
collection-luatex 1
collection-mathscience 1
collection-metapost 1
collection-pictures 1
collection-plaingeneric 1
instopt_adjustpath 1
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 1
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 1
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 0
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 0
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 1
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 1
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
tlpdbopt_sys_bin /usr/local/bin
tlpdbopt_sys_info /usr/local/share/info
tlpdbopt_sys_man /usr/local/share/man
tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user 0
```

Comment: Does a plain LuaTeX document compile (or even a `\starttext A\stoptext` with context)?

Comment: @TeXnician \starttext A\stoptext with context works, plain tex file compiled with luatex works.

Comment: the log should start like ./aa933.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01> pre-release-6
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2018/09/24 2.90001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2018-09-21 2.6 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2018-09-21 2.6 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/names.

Comment: so it is probably having problems rebuilding your font cache, did it actually quit or was it taking a long time and you killed it?

Comment: Can you run on a command line `luaotfload-tool -u` to update the font database? (add if needed -v to see a few messages).

Comment: I don't kill anything. I start the installation, gone for a 2 hours walk, and when I came back the installation was finished. Consécutively to your comment, I rebuild the font cache, all the formats and ran mktexlsr. Not better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done. No output in the terminal. Not better for the compilation.

Comment: When you run luaotfload-tool --help it should tell you the name and location of the font databases. Where are they? Do they exist? Are they new?

Comment: I forgot to `sudo`. Now the previously non existing databases are generated in : The font cache will be written to
   /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/
But not better for the compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With -v option : luaotfload | db : Updating the font names database.
luaotfload | db : Scanning TEXMF for fonts...
luaotfload | db : Scanning system fonts...
luaotfload | db : Scanning 3327 collected font files ...

Comment: With the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a new install with the same texlive.profile and it fails on the same problem.

I successfully made a new install with this texlive.profile. Maybe someone can understand why the previous fails.

```
    # texlive.profile written on Sun Sep 30 20:46:10 2018 UTC
# It will NOT be updated and reflects only the
# installation profile at installation time.
selected_scheme scheme-custom
TEXDIR /usr/local/texlive/2018
TEXMFCONFIG ~/.texlive2018/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME ~/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var
binary_x86_64-linux 1
collection-basic 1
collection-bibtexextra 1
collection-binextra 1
collection-context 1
collection-fontsextra 1
collection-fontsrecommended 1
collection-fontutils 1
collection-formatsextra 1
collection-games 1
collection-humanities 1
collection-langcyrillic 1
collection-langenglish 1
collection-langfrench 1
collection-langgerman 1
collection-langgreek 1
collection-latex 1
collection-latexextra 1
collection-latexrecommended 1
collection-luatex 1
collection-mathscience 1
collection-metapost 1
collection-pictures 1
collection-plaingeneric 1
collection-xetex 1
instopt_adjustpath 1
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 1
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 1
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 1
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 1
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 1
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 1
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
tlpdbopt_sys_bin /usr/local/bin
tlpdbopt_sys_info /usr/local/share/info
tlpdbopt_sys_man /usr/local/share/man
tlpdbopt_w32_multi_user 1
```